# What is an OEM package?

Tags: windows-10-iot-core

I was trying to make custome image of Windows IoT Core. There is mentioned "Combining provisioning package with OEM Package". So What is OEM Packages and why it is use in custome image creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifically OEM standards for Original Equipment Manufacturer.

It will be in use in custom image creator as the base image for the operating system before any changes are made beyond Microsoft's original version.

The base image (OEM) + your image = the new OS image.

Answer (score 0):

OEM Packages indicate that Microsoft is the OEM for the base image but the company publishing the image is the entity customizing the image with its own config and software (as an end product for its own customers).